# Firefox isn't rendering properly SVG image border

Tags: html, css, firefox, svg, border-image

I am using the image below (SVG) as `border-image`.

[image: wood border]

Works perfectly in **Chrome** and **Safari**, but **Firefox** has a different rendering. Is there any way to fix this?

**Chrome and Safari:**

[image: webkit]

**Firefox:**

[image: gecko]

and... **My code:**

```css
body { margin: 10px; }

.box {
  background: beige;
  border: 20px solid sandybrown;

  -o-border-image: url(https://web.archive.org/web/20170919223208/http://imgh.us/wood-border.svg) 70 stretch;
  -moz-border-image: url(https://web.archive.org/web/20170919223208/http://imgh.us/wood-border.svg) 70 stretch;
  -ms-border-image: url(https://web.archive.org/web/20170919223208/http://imgh.us/wood-border.svg) 70 stretch;
  -webkit-border-image: url(https://web.archive.org/web/20170919223208/http://imgh.us/wood-border.svg) 70 stretch;
  border-image: url(https://web.archive.org/web/20170919223208/http://imgh.us/wood-border.svg) 70 stretch;

  height: 100px;
}
```

```html
<div class="box">
</div>
```

Comment: have you tried repeat ?  border-image: url(http://imgh.us/wood-border.svg) 80  repeat; ... your svg has some funny size, full pixels and eventually squared  would help ...

Comment: It's a known issue: https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=619500

Comment: Apparently got fixed. VTCing as "can't repro"